# Grabbing first or last value for custom time period

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap, cube

First off, very new to SSAS.  But what I would like to accomplish seems fairly trivial (I hope).

I have transactional data which occurs by the second.  And I have created two time dimensions.  One dimension is based on the standard time dimension using the time dimension wizard.  The other is a time dimension that was generated by my own script where I have a record for each second of the day.

I've linked my fact table to my dimensions and have my cube deployed properly.  Within my fact data, one of the attributes is price. Now using min and max I have been able to obtain the highest price and lowest price which occurred over a specific time period.  What I would like to obtain is the first and last price that occurred over a time period.  I've tried using "first value" and "last value" but what is being returned is not correct, it seems to be some sort of aggregation.

So for example. If my prices over a 1 minute period were:

1233, 1233.85, 1300,1250

First should return, 1233 and last should return 1250.  This should work at all time periods.

To add, for my custom time dimension I've tried setting its type to "Time" but the results remain the same.  I appreciate any suggestions.  I am basically looking to get the first value of the underlying and the last value.

Example query that gets me part of the way there:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
     { [Measures].[High]
     , [Measures].[Low]
     , [Measures].[Price Count]
     , [Measures].[Price]
     } ON COLUMNS
     , NON EMPTY
     { [Dim Date].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
     * HEAD( [Dim Time].[Hour - Second].[Second].ALLMEMBERS )
     } ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
```

[image]

Notice that the price count column has multiple records.  I need the first record from within here I don't want the actual sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new measure that gets the Price for the first second of the time dimension. For example, if you want the first second of the day, then you don't need it in the cross join on the rows, but you can get the first second of the [Hour - Second] hierarchy inside a calculated measure:

```
with
    member [Measures].[First Price] as
        (head(descendants([Dim Time].[Hour - Second].CurrentMember, Second)), [Measures].[Price])
select
    non empty {
        [Measures].[High],
        [Measures].[Low],
        [Measures].[Price Count],
        [Measures].[Price] 
    } on columns,   
    {
        [Dim Date].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
    } on rows
from
    [Cube]
```

If you want the time periods smaller, e.g. by hour, try something like:

```
    non empty {
        [Dim Date].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Time].[Hour - Second].[Hour]
    } on rows
```